# using nodegit within angularjs app

Tags: node.js, angularjs, github

I am building an app in AngularJS that needs to clone GitHub wikis attached to GitHub repos. The GitHub API does not have functionality to do anything with the GitHub wikis and GitHub support suggested I could use libgit2. With that in mind, I found [nodegit](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit).

So, now I have nodegit installed, and I made a basic javascript file out of the code example they have for [Cloning a repository and reading a file](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit#cloning-a-repository-and-reading-a-file). I have that file, called nodegit.js, working and by navigating to the folder containing it and typing

```
node ./nodegit.js
```

The script runs great and clones the repo into the temp folder.

Fantastic.

Now...how can I use this script in my angularjs app?

1. Is there a way to run a node script from angular?
2. Is there a way to use nodegit from angular itself?
3. Is there some other angular->github **non-GitHub API** script out there?

Any help greatly appreciated. I've gotten stuck on this one.

thank you,

Scott

Comment: Think of the node portion separately since it will be executed on the server but the angular will be executed on the client.  You will want to send a request using $http or otherwise from Angular to the node server which when it gets said requests should run the function you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks shaunhusain. I ended up setting up an ExpressJS server via NodeJS and putting my code there and calling the ExpressJS server from my Angular app.

thanks, scott

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that I currently have a strong focus on getting the library running in the browser to address this use case.  I'll update this comment once the code has landed.  An issue to track the status is here:

https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/142